# Delete a pointer in cpp and the new operator

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, delete-operator, assertion

May I have to delete a pointer only if i use new ?
I tried a code like this :

```
std::vector<float>* intersections;

    intersections=&KIN_Trigonometry::getIntersectionCircleAndLine( xA, yA, xB, yB, x, y, radius * 2, nbPoints);

    delete intersections;
```

it give me Assertion failure ...
I already used delete with a pointer when I was using new like

```
int* p = new int[2];
delete p;
```

Thanks for your support

Comment: either `getIntersectionCircleAndLine` returns a reference to a member variable (on the stack, most likely option), or it allocates memory, returns a pointer to it, but decided to manage the memory (i.e., call `delete[]`) on it afterwards. Either way, a double delete is happening and You Probably Shouldn't Do That

Comment: Thanks man ! I think so too , I didn't understood why negative votes with my topic......

Comment: Can you show the signature of the KIN_Trigonometry::getIntersectionCircleAndLine function please?

Comment: static std::vector<float> getIntersectionCircleAndLine(float xl, float yl, float xl2, float yl2, float xC, float yC, float r, int circlesPoints);

Comment: @sachaamm, It doesn't compile, how did you manage to compile it? [my code](http://pastebin.com/kZCgYiGv)

Comment: @zarathustra , Well , in contrary of what Sergey said this code is compiling , even the return doesn't return the vector with values added , it just return an empty vector :  std::vector<float>* intersections2;
  //*intersections2 = std::vector<float>(); // this line is causing break error

  intersections2 = &KIN_Trigonometry::getIntersectionCircleAndLine2(A.x, A.y, B.x, B.y, x, y, radius * 2, nbPoints);

  cout << (*intersections2).size() << endl;   // COMPILING , and write 0 even we add values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of your example code `int* p = new int[2]; delete p;`, you created a new array, so you should use `delete[]` rather than `delete`

See cplusplus reference: [operator delete[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[]/)

Meanwhile, I realize you're asking about the code block above that.  Since you are not allocating the object with `operator new` then you should not be using `operator delete` nor `operator delete[]` to deallocate it.  That is your problem.

Chances are, you probably want to use `free()` to deallocate this object, if you are to deallocate it at all.  You will want to check the code or its documentation to be sure.

Based on the fact that you're taking the address of the function's return value, I don't think you should ever be deallocating this yourself at all.

Comment: it's the same result with delete[]

Comment: surely not. std::vector is not allocated by new[]. It is not an 'array' as far as c++ is concerned, it is one object

Comment: This answer actually refers to his example code `int* p = new int[2]; delete p; `

Comment: ah yes - but his example has no relationship to his problem. He is taking the address of the return value and then deleting - nothing good can come of that

Comment: you should never use `delete` nor `delete[]` in the case that the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 4):

note the 'intersection = &....' You are taking the address of the return value, that doesnt make you the owner of it.

I suspect you should be doing

```
std::vector<float> & intersections=KIN_Trigonometry::getIntersectionCircleAndLine( xA, yA, xB, yB, x, y, radius * 2, nbPoints);
```

or maybe

```
std::vector<float>  intersections=KIN_Trigonometry::getIntersectionCircleAndLine( xA, yA, xB, yB, x, y, radius * 2, nbPoints);
```

you have to check the signature of the get function

Comment: Yes thanks , but I'm using several ways to get a vector of float return by a static method , everything is compiling fine but when I try to get the size of intersections I've got error : Error 5 error C3867: 'std::vector<float,std::allocator<_Ty>>::size': function call missing argument list; use '&std::vector<float,std::allocator<_Ty>>::size' to create a pointer to member

Comment: This should not even compile.

Comment: @sachaamm: That's unrelated. You fix it by adding () : `size_t sz = intersections.size( );`

Comment: @MSalters : Right , that's it

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete `intersections` in your first statement because intersections (as far as we can see here) has no allocated space, it's just a link to an adress. So you have to allocate a memory space to `intersections` using `new` and then delete this memory space.

Answer (score 0):

This code should not even compile.

```
intersections = &KIN_Trigonometry::getIntersectionCircleAndLine(...);
```

Tries to take an address of a returned temporary, and this is prohibited. You are either compiling the code with the Very Bad Compiler, or you are not giving us the real code.

Comment: it compiles with Visual Studio 2013 , but I get error when I try to get anything from intersections ( like the size of the vector ) . And KIN_Trigonometry() is a static vector<float> ( i don't know if it does matter ? )

Comment: std::vector<float>* intersections2;
  //*intersections2 = std::vector<float>(); // this causes a break error

  intersections2 = &KIN_Trigonometry::getIntersectionCircleAndLine2(A.x, A.y, B.x, B.y, x, y, radius * 2, nbPoints); // compile

  cout << (*intersections2).size() << endl; // compile , cout "0" even we added values